# apache/superset has no GROUP by. why not?

Tags: apache-superset

Have a good day.

My version - without GROUP BY:
[image: My version]

Normal human version - with GROUP BY:
[image: Normal human version]

After installing superset using the instructions (https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose) and connecting MySQL database I found, that "groupable" (GROUP BY) is not avaliable in my superset, but everyware in examples i see this option like default.

what i want to do? and why it does not work default? i try found information about it, but perhaps my searches are incorrect. because i have no answers yet.
maybe i need some extra config settings

if you have some ideas please tell me.
Thank you!

---

i try different versions superset;
change some options in "superset/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py";
cant find table settings from superset druid examples.

My datasets list view:
[image: my datasets list view]

Dataset settings only:
[image: dataset settings only]

Comment: Some possibilities: (1) you could be running a different version of Superset, click the Settings menu in the top right and your version number will be listed at the bottom.  (2) Are you using different chart types in those two screenshots?